# Make blog posts 3 row and 3 column

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I make it 3 column and 3 row then pagination in order to use empty spaces. Check "Music Title" [here](https://devoiders.com/artists/50-cent).

Here is the code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<h3 class="m-t-none"><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'title-music', esc_html__('Music', 'musik') ); ?></h3>
<div class="list-group list-group-lg">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="list-group-item">
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'download-list' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="row">
<h3 class="m-t-none col-xs-12 col-sm-3"><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'title-music', esc_html__('Music', 'musik') ); ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="list-group list-group-lg">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="list-group-item">
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'download-list' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination' ); ?>
```

Comment: What specific area is decorated?

Comment: Please upvote and select the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: The "Artists" came under the pagination
and the first item in Music Title went into the center, that's it